# Limit cases for the Doppler effect

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, doppler-effect

When considering a wave emitting source and an observer that are in relative motion, one usually chooses between the classical Doppler effect and the relativistic Doppler effect depending on the velocity $v$ of the waves involved: the classical one for waves with $v\ll c$ and the relativistic one for electromagnetic waves with velocity $c$,

$$
\frac{f_{r}}{f_{s}}=\left(\frac{c \pm v_{\mathrm{r}}}{c \pm v_{\mathrm{s}}}\right) , \quad \frac{f_{r}}{f_{s}}=\sqrt{\frac{1-\beta}{1+\beta}}
$$

However, there are two situations in which it would not be clear to me which of the two effects should be used:

1. If the source and receiver are moving in a medium of refractive index $n$, and the emitted wave is electromagnetic, then it will move with a velocity $v=c/n$. As in this case $v<c$, would the formula for the relativistic Doppler effect still hold for this case, or should it be modified?
2. On the other hand, if the relative velocity between the source and the observer is relativistic, $\beta \in (0.5,1) $, but the velocity of the wave in the reference frame of the source is not relativistic, which Doppler effect should be used?

Comment: For #1, since  $c/n$ is effectively the max possible speed (I'm ignoring particles w/ mass), stick with the relativistic form.  For #2 I think you have to recall "Frame of Reference" and the rules of Special Relativity; are you moving with the observer? (that's a hint)